# Deleted comments leave badge on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

When someone leaves a comment that involves you being notified, you get the notification both on the main toolbar on Stack Exchange and as a notification/badge on the iOS app.

If you read a comment on the website and cause the notification to be removed from the toolbar, the badge also gets removed from the iOS app.

However, when a comment that has previously caused a notification/badge to appear on iOS gets deleted, the badge remains on the iOS app while the notification gets removed from the website toolbar.  Could the badge also be removed from the iOS app in this situation?